# Retrieving JSON object using a html link and displaying the json data on an another html page

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, innerhtml, getelementbyid, template-literals

I have two html pages and I want to retrieve a JSON object when the user clicks from the first html page link.Links have different Id's when I clicks first link on the first page I want to get the first information.The problem is which-ever link I click it shows all the information from data.I need a way to solve it.Thanks in advance

```
(1st html page)

<a href="2nd-page.html" id="one">info 1</a> <br><br>
<a href="2nd-page.html" id="two">info 2</a>
```

```js
const data = [
    {
    
        id: "two",
        h1: "this is test two",
        p: "sum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC",
        list: `
             <li>dog</li>
             <li>fox</li>
             <li>cat</li>
            `
        },
    
    {
    id: "one",
    h1: "this is a test one",
    p: "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.",
    list: `
             <li>red</li>
             <li>Blue</li>
             <li>yellow</li>

    `


    } 

]

document.getElementById("heading").innerHTML = `${data.map(function(unit){return unit.h1})}`
document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = `${data.map(function(unit){return unit.p})}`
document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = `${data.map(function(unit){return unit.list})}`
```

```html
<!-- 2nd html page -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h2 id="heading"></h2>
    <p id="paragraph"></p>
    <ul id="list"></ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The hyperlinks both go to the same page... what are you expecting to occur?

Comment: Add a URL parameter ``<a href="2nd-page.html?id=two" id="two">info 2</a>`` and then display the data based on the URL parameter.

Comment: 2nd page is like a template when I click the first page hpyerlink it should fill the 2nd page  elements(h2,p,ul)according to the js data

Comment: How do you expect it to magically know which link you clicked before? This is what @Dula showed you. Add parameters to the URL so you know which data to display.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might solve your case. Thanks to @Dula and @Peter Krebs
(1st page)

```
<a href="2nd-page.html?id=one" >info 1</a> <br><br>

<a href="2nd-page.html?id=two" >info 2</a>
```

```js
const data = {
  one: {
    h1: "this is a test one",
    p: "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.",
    list: `
             <li>red</li>
             <li>Blue</li>
             <li>yellow</li>
    `
    },
    two: {
        h1: "this is test two",
        p: "sum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC",
        list: `
             <li>dog</li>
             <li>fox</li>
             <li>cat</li>
    `
    }
}


function get_parameter( parameter_name ){
    let parameters = new URLSearchParams( window.location.search );
    return parameters.get( parameter_name );
}
past_id = get_parameter("id")
unit = data[past_id]

document.getElementById("heading").innerHTML = unit.h1
document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = unit.p
document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = unit.list
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h2 id="heading"></h2>
    <p id="paragraph"></p>
    <ul id="list"></ul>
<script src="your js file path.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks.I think that solves part of the problem..But it still shows all the info whichever link I click